# Cannot create windows HVM with SDL in xen 4.4.1

Tags: xen, video, virtualization

I want to create a win HVM, and set `sdl=1`. I was able to do so. But after I upgraded to xen-4.4.1, I got this error

```
libxl: error: libxl_dm.c:1371:device_model_spawn_outcome: domain 4 device model: spawn failed (rc=-3)
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1186:domcreate_devmodel_started: device model did not start: -3
libxl: error: libxl_dm.c:1475:kill_device_model: Device Model already exited
```

And the debug message is at https://bpaste.net/show/a61c34e54908

If I set `vnc=1`, the VM works well. But it is really inconvenient to install windows with vnc.

The only line that looks suspicious in the debug message is:

```
"vga": { "kind": "cirrus" }
```

I have no idea how to configure that value. I also tried to install the *cirrus* video driver, but doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Seems you got the answer per your reply on Xen list - http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.xen.user/cutoff=83841

Comment: oh~yeah. I figured it out myself and replied that list :)